# Suddenly lethargic Antenna/ Suckermouth catfish

Tags: aquarium, fish

I've got a 31,7 gallon tank in which about 35 fishes live.
For cleaner fishes it is:  2 Antenna catfish (black and brown) and since almost 4 weeks now also 5 
armored catfish (others are all non cleaner fish).

While 1 antenna catfish was lazy to start with the other (black) was always very very (hyper)active. 
Moving along the glass window constantly and cleaning / eating. Also he was within minutes on a 
fodder tablet when it was thrown in.

A good week ago his behaviour changed almost over night. He is almost constantly only at 1 location
and ignores the fodder tablets completely. He still changes places on the glass, but not constantly like before 
but more like 1-3 times per day in total.

Other things I noticed

- The fish is under 1 year in age. He is in the tank since 2-3 months.
- If a fish gets too near and tries to bite him...he reacts as aggresively as in the past
- When he moves a bit along the glass I do not notice any lack of strength with him holding onto the glass (thus as strong as always)
- There is nothing on his body that seems like it changed (no inflated stomach or visible fungus, ...)
- There was a problem with the filter 4 weeks ago which quite a few fishes their lives (I overlooked that I had to remove the filter compltely to see if it is too dirty to work any longer....lesson learnt even if it was a very sad one back then).
  Aside from that and one homicidal fish in the tank there is nothing that seems to have changed or is out of order.
- Fishes are fed with the tablets and flake lining (same as since months).

As I know from past experiences a sudden behvaioural change is almost never a good sign I'm quite a bit distressed 
there, but at a loos as to what to do (or if I'm overreacting and that change is normal).

So the question is: Is there anything I can do there or look out for?

Comment: As a small update that one fish died today. But dtill interested in what i could have done additionally

Comment: Someone mentioned to me that its not antenna catfish (a straight translation into english) but instead  Suckermouth Catfish.  I corrected the title appropriately, but could someone clarify if that is correct so? tnx

Comment: hei @Thomas your tanks is small for a Hypostomus plecostomus, check your water parameters and say it, is important to know how is your water for determiante what happend here.

Comment: @Gawey not sure I correctly calculated it (size).  it is a 120L tank. From what I heard that fish needs at least a 100L tank? or am I wrong?

Comment: u are wrong, just search "plecostomus" size and u will see that is a 60cm of fish. So is a best option for this tank one ancistrus than him.